# In Python, how to use Locust and Requests package?

Tags: python, python-requests, locust

I'm not quite sure how to form this question with specificity, so hopefully it'll make sense..

I have a http client that uses the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package and now I'd like to use [locust](https://locust.io/) to run load tests.

To use Locust properly, looks like I should extend [HttpLocust](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.core.HttpLocust), which uses locust's `client` for the http requests, but my class already has its own client, that makes the requests.

So I'm not sure how to use locust..  should I just use the [Locust](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.core.Locust) class and forget about `HttpLocust`?

Have you created Locust tests using the Requests packages? Any pointers?

Any other python http load test framework you recommend instead?

Comment: Just from the gist of that Locust link, it sounds like you'll want to extend the HttpLocust class. `Locust` sounds like it's for non-http hits (TCP, database connections come to mind).
It doesn't seem like you "can't" use a client to attach to the Locust class however.

Just wanted to comment to say thanks as well. I was looking for a load testing framework too. Hadn't heard of this one before.

Comment: just create your client in the locustfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HttpLocust class already uses the requests package, so you can use that instead of your client.

If you want to use your client, you should extend the Locust class. For example:

```
class MyHttpLocust(Locust):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyHttpLocust, self).__init__()
        if not self.host:
            raise LocustError('host is missing')

        self.client = MyHttpClient(self.host)
```